# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

Answer (score 0):

check if you can update your flutter version

Also you could try flutter clean, and then flutter pub get